# Python : How to break the python mysql query line

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi, mysql-python

Currently what i have is..

```
cursor.execute ("insert into incoming set  raw='" + f2 + "',  from_em='"+ a2 +"', to2='" + a1 + "'")
```

i am trying to make this easy to read for myself.

so i tried to break it into multiple lines.

```
cursor.execute ("insert into incoming set
raw='" + f2 + "',
from_em='"+ a2 +"',
to2='" + a1 + "'
")
```

this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cursor.execute ("insert into incoming set  raw='" 
+ f2 + 
"',  from_em='" 
+ a2 + 
"', to2='" 
+ a1 + "'")
```

In this case it's not necessary to use `\` to separate lines because the whole expression is inside parenthesis, but notice that you can't split a line *before* a closing quote character is reached. But to be fair, it'd be a better idea to use string formatting here - it's clearer:

```
s = "insert into incoming set raw='{0}', from_em='{1}', to2='{2}'"
cursor.execute(s.format(f2, a2, a1))
```

Comment: Why did you put backslashes ? They are completely useless because of the parentheses.

Comment: index in {} in this case is not mandatory.
and i like to format with dict

`d = {'a1':a1,'a2':a2,'f2':f2};
cursor.execute("insert into incoming set raw='{f2}', from_em='{a2}', to2='{a1}'".format(d))`

Comment: The original answer was better with the backward slashes, which is what i ended up using, i currently do not use the python's "mysql injection safe method" for my mysql queries, i prefer php style or regular mysql style mysql queries, i deal with security issues externally.  - Sumer Kolcak

Comment: @PythonQuestions: You are making a terrible mistake. Getting injection-safety right without prepared statements is horribly error-prone. Anyone who knows what they're doing well enough to get it right knows that prepared statements are a better option.

Answer (score 3):

First: Don't build SQL commands like this. You'll get [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead, use a prepared statement. With that said, on to the answer.

You can't break a line in the middle of a string literal (unless you backslash-ignore the newline or you're in a triple-quoted string). Instead, break it like this:

```
cursor.execute("insert into incoming set  raw='" + f2 + "',  from_em='"
               + a2 +"', to2='" + a1 + "'")
```

Note that Python doesn't count a newline as the end of a statement if it's in the middle of unmatched parentheses, brackets, or braces. This is the [PEP 8-preferred](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) way to do line continuation in Python, rather than using backslashes.